# JSTL Cannot be resolved error

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have seen similar questions and the answer suggested is place the JSTL jar in the classpath. I have tried both jstl.jar and jstl 1.1.jar bit My error is persistent. The Jars are coming in my web_inf/lib directory so I do not Understand what the problem is. I am using Tomcat 7

My Jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
.............
```

My Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
    ......
```

My lib Directory After Deployment:

[image: My WEB_INF/lib Directory]

What Should I do I am running out of Options :P

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, check if the libraries are listed in `Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries`

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSTL 1.1 also requires **Standard.jar**.

The standard.jar (taglib) library is used to enable the JSTL expression language in JSP page, and it’s always used together with the jstl.jar together.

[**Download**](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/) and add it to your lib folder.

---

Or You can use [**JSTL 1.2**](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C707331597) which does not require standard.jar and also provides performance improvements.

Comment: JSTL 1.2 did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `jstl-1.2.1` for `Tomcat7`

Download [JSTL 1.2.1 jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.1)